# AS3 Dynamic text box over button

Tags: actionscript-3, button, textbox

In AS3 I have a button on the stage and above it I create a textbox box dynamically with code.
My problem is that the area that is under the text (i.e. that part of the button) is no longer clickable.

I have set:
tBox.selectable = false;
but that doesn't solve it.

Any ideas

Season greetings,
Luben

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [InteractiveObject.mouseEnabled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#mouseEnabled):

`textField.mouseEnabled=false;`

Answer (score 0):

If you set `component.visible` to false it does not interact with the user.

So, if you set `tBox.visible = false` then it will be invisible and the button will become clickable. Just a thought, but overlapping components is really bad UI design. If you have space on your stage, you should consider keeping them separate

Comment: But then the textBox will no longer be visible!

Comment: @weltraumpirat, thats the point. If you don't want it to interact with the mouse, why would you have a textbox? It makes no sense whatsoever to have a textbox over a button. You might as well have just a button and change its `text`

Comment: The text property exists only on a UIButton, which is a rather heavy component, compared to SimpleButton.  You can have lots of custom buttons that don't extend UIComponent, and you might still want your button to display a text. You can then encapsulate these - where would that be bad UI design?

Comment: You can even use Sprites to act as buttons, by the way.  No need for big frameworks.

Comment: He doesn;t specify SinpleButton, does he? One can only assume he meant the normal Button class

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that text field (despite it's transparent) is lying over button. To make click on button possible you have to be sure that button is in front of text. Take a look at [AddChildAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt%28%29) method of DisplayObject. Objects with greater position index are lying over objects with lower position index. So all you need is to make sure that button has greater index:

```
container.addChildAt(button, 1)
...
container.addChildAt(text, 0)
```

P.S.: you may embed button dirrectly into text field using html `<a href="javascript:..."><img src="link_to_image"><a/>` or something like that.

Comment: Making the text appear below a button image won't solve anything. Plus, the embedded javascript is a horrible workaround.

Comment: puting -1 for attempt to answer is not right. If all will act as you, no users will try to answer.

Comment: Down voting for a misleading answer, or one that is *wrong* is totally legit. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers